# TransactionScope and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to wrap some pieces of code around a `TransactionScope`. The code inside this `using` statement calls a managed C++ library, which will call some unmanaged code. I do also want to update my database, which is using Entity Framework.

Here comes the problem, when doing `SaveChanges` on the `DbContext` inside the `TransactionScope` I always get some sort of Timeout exception in the database layer. I've googled this, and it seems to be a fairly common problem but I haven't found any applicable answers to my problem. This is a snippet of my code

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
       try
       {
           //Do call to the managed C++ Library
           using (var dbContext = _dbContextFactory.Create())
           {
            //doing some CRUD Operations on the DbContext
            //Probably some more dbContext related stuff

            dbContext.SaveChanges(); //Results with a timeout 
           }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
          transactionScope.Dispose();
          throw;
        }
}
```

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3 so I can access the `BeginTransaction` on the database, but I also need wrap the C++ calls inside a `TransactionScope`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how long does this transaction take to process?

Comment: @Claies Under normal circumstances this should only take around 500 ms or so. Its a pretty quick operation.

Comment: the default timeout is 1 minutes, but maybe using the default constructor does not match your need, maybe you should check timeout limit and isolation level for your TransactionScope.

Comment: @EmmanuelM I forgot to add the isolationLevel to this post. But I'm using `ReadUncommited`

Comment: and did you try to increase the timeout ? (even if it should not take more than 500ms it could be useful to try it)

Comment: Looks like the unmanaged code keeps a lock on some data.

Comment: Don't forget to call complete on the Transaction Scope; transactionScope.Complete()

Comment: @Craig: He doesn't need to call Complete() or Dispose(). The "using" block does that for him, even in the event of an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass in `TransactionScopeOptions` defining your timeout (How long to keep the transaction open). An example for the absolute upper limit of timeouts would be:

```
            TransactionOptions to = new TransactionOptions();
            to.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
            to.Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout;
            using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, to)) { }
```

You should definitely be aware of the impact of such a long-running transaction, this isn't typically required, and I'd highly recommend using something below MaximumTimeout which reflects how long you expect it to run. You should do your best to keep the time period for which the transaction is held as small as possible, doing any processing that doesn't have to be a single transaction outside the transaction scope.

It's also worth noting that depending on the underlying database it can enforce it's own limitations on transaction durations if configured to do so.

Comment: I only get the same exception: `Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding` on the SaveChanges()

Comment: Oh, that timeout doesn't relate to the Transaction, just to the single command. Assuming dbContext is an EF database context you can set the timeout per command with `((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;` (or however many seconds you want - that represents 5 minutes)